# Trying to get the cpu usage of a specified process on different servers

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

Basically I'm trying to write a script which will retrieve the cpu usage of a process(multiple processes specified in a XML file) from different servers inside a network.

I'm trying to use Invoke-Command to run the script, add the resulting table to collectionVariable and finally convert the result to Html.

Table format

```
$Format = @"
<style>
TABLE {width:90%;margin-left:5%; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; 
border-color: black; border-collapse: collapse;}
TH {border-width: 1px; padding: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: 
black; background-color: #6495ED;}
TD {border-width: 1px; padding: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: 
black;}
</style>
"@
```

Function to parse the xml file with the credentials

```
function parseXmlCredential {
[xml]$xml1 = get-content xmlCredentials\*.xml

$servers = $xml1.Configuration.servers;
$names = $xml1.Configuration.name;
$username = $xml1.Configuration.username;
$password = $xml1.Configuration.password;

$server = $servers -split ','
$name = $names -split ','

return $server, $name, $username, $password
}

$server, $name, $username, $password = parseXmlCredential;
```

Properties of the item to be selected

```
 $properties = @(
 @{Name = 'Server';  Expression = { $server}},
 @{Name = "Process Name";Expression ={$_.Name}},
 @{Name = "Process Id";Expression = {$_.Id}},
 @{Name = 'CPUPercent(%)';Expression = {
      $TotalSec = (New-TimeSpan -Start $_.StartTime).TotalSeconds
      [Math]::Round( ($_.CPU * 100 / $TotalSec), 2)}},
 @{Name ="Memory (MB)";Expression = {[Math]::Round(($_.privatememorysize / 1mb),2)}}
 )
```

Inside it I will store the resulting tables for each process

```
$collectionVariable = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
```

Accessing all servers

```
foreach($j in $server)
 {
 $server = $j
```

For each server I retrieve data for all the required processes

```
foreach($i in $name)
 {
 $rezultat = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $j -ScriptBlock {

 $table = Get-Process | 
 Where-Object {$_.Name -like $i+'*' } |
 Where-Object {$_.Name -notmatch "^(idle|_total|system)$"} |
 Select-Object  $properties |
 Sort-Object -Property *CPUPercent* -Descending |
 ConvertTo-Html -As TABLE -Fragment |
 Out-String

 $collectionVariable.Add($table) | Out-Nul
   } -ArgumentList $i,(,$properties),(,$collectionVariable) 
  } 
 }
```

Convert the result to Html

```
ConvertTo-Html -Head $Format -PostContent $collectionVariable |
 Out-File //the out file
```

As a result I should have a html page with tables for each process, but I get the following error.

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
+ PSComputerName        : osvm2309

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
+ PSComputerName        : osvm2309

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
+ PSComputerName        : osvm2256

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
+ PSComputerName        : osvm2256

ConvertTo-Html : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'PostContent'. The 
argument is null, empty, or an element of the argument collection 
contains a null value. Supply a collection that does not contain any null 
values and then try the command again.
At C:\Users\lucianp\Downloads\processes_details_powershell\script.ps1:72 
char:43
+ ConvertTo-Html -Head $Header -PostContent $collectionVariable |
+                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [ConvertTo-Html], 
ParameterBindingValidationException    +FullyQualifiedErrorIdParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertToHtmlCommand
```

Comment: the error msgs from PoSh _usually_ include a line number & the code that PoSh thinks triggered the error. so ... where is that info? right now, your error is not associated with any particular bit of the code you posted. [*sigh ...*]

Comment: I posted the full eror.

Comment: kool! thanks for posting the info ... i was rather curious about it! [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:
The problem was with the collectionVariable, I was trying to add the result inside the Invoke-Command.Instead, I should add $rezultat outside the invoke-command, right afer it.